# Make a CompareValidator validate conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have a checkbox which has a javascript function that is called onclick to show/hide a div as below. In the div is a textbox with a CompareValidator which validates the text in the textbox as a Double. The problem is that the CV fires when the checkbox is checked and the div is displayed,  and the error message appears by default because it seems like the CV is validating an empty textbox which is not a double. Is there a way to make the CV validate after the checkbox has made the div visible and/or only when the text in the textbox is not null and is not an empty string? Thank you.

```
        <table id="tblLabTests" class="fullWidth dataEntryTableTop" runat="server" visible="false" clientidmode="Static">
            <tr id="trL_FBC" clientidmode="static">
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkL_FBC" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
                    <asp:Label AssociatedControlID="chkL_FBC" ID="lblL_FBC" runat="server" Text="FBC" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="divFBC" runat="server" clientidmode="static">
                        <table id="tblFBC" class="fullWidth noBorder" runat="server" clientidmode="static">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPlateletCount" runat="server" Text="Platelet Count" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPlateletCount" runat="server" MaxLength="4" CssClass="width50" />                                        
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server">*10<sup>9</sup>/L</asp:Label><br />
                                    <asp:CompareValidator ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="cvRed" runat="server" id="CompareValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtPlateletCount" Type="Double" ErrorMessage="Must be a number" Display="Dynamic" Operator="DataTypeCheck" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        function fbcUpdate() {
            var checked = $('#chkL_FBC').is(':checked');
            if (checked) {
                $('#divFBC').css('display', '');
            }
            else {
                $('#divFBC').css('display', 'none');
            }
        }
```

Comment: You mean `if($('#txtPlateletCount').val() !== ''){/* do your stuff here */}`?

Comment: @PHPglue OK that looks feasible, so in the do your stuff here section are you advocating enabling the CV? I have tried enabling and disabling the cv but to no avail. What is the syntax please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I've abandoned this strategy. The code behind uses Entity Framework so I've added validation to the entity from the code behind. Thank you.